# Electron & Sentry: how to NOT merge tags/contexts when running multiple electron processes

Tags: electron, sentry

I have an Electron.js app and along with normal main process I also `spawn` a copy of the main process. In the copy of the main process I load c++ native modules which can cause issues on certain machines in production and I collect telemetry for that spawned process.

**sandbox.ts**

```js
...
export const isSandbox = (): boolean => process.env.SANDBOXED === '1';
...
if (isSandbox()) {
   console.log('startSandbox - already in sandbox');
   return;
}

const exePath = app.getPath("exe");

const spawnProcess = spawn(exePath, process.argv.slice(1), {
  env: {
    ...process.env,
    SANDBOXED: "1",
  },
});
...
```

I also use Sentry to collect native crashes of the app. I initialize it this way:

**index.ts** - this file runs in both normal and spawned "sandboxed" process

```js
...
const SentryEnv = import.meta.env.VITE_SENTRY_ENVIRONMENT;
if (["testing", "beta", "production"].includes(SentryEnv))
  Sentry.init({
    dsn: "https://000@sentry.myapp.app/1",
    environment: SentryEnv,
  });
Sentry.setTag("sandbox", isSandbox());
...
```

However what happens is that the main 1st process sets the tag always to false, no matter if the error was raised from the main or from the spawned process.

[image: Sentry sandbox false]

I guess it's how Sentry merges contexts.

How can I achieve what I need? So that spawned process errors are marked as `Sandbox: true` in the Sentry UI and the normal main process errors are marked as `Sandbox: false`?

Answer (score 0):

Found a workaround:

**index.ts**

```js
  if (isSandbox()) {
    crashReporter.addExtraParameter('sandbox', '1');
  } else {
    crashReporter.addExtraParameter('sandbox', '0');
  }
```

If I set dmp metadata using Electron `crashReporter` API they then appear in Sentry UI correctly.